# Java regex to find two or more consecutive or non-consecutive dots in word

Tags: java, regex

What's the best regex to know that a word in a sentence has two or more consecutive or non-consecutive dots?

Example:

```
Non match:
    This does not have a multiple dots. This is a normal line of sentences.

Match:
    This should match because www.site.com has two dots.
    This should also match since dot.andanotherdot. has two dots.
    Consecutive dots like this ..dots is also matching.
```

I found a lot of questions that might relate to this but usually, they only need to find consecutive. Or they need to find it within the line not by a word-per-word lookup.

Comment: In your first line "This does not have a multiple dots. This is a normal line of sentences." Are you including full stops ?

Comment: Yes @Adya, but it's good to have solutions for both with and without full stops :)

Comment: You need AI for this. jk. It would be pretty simple if you have each sentence in a separate line. Otherwise, you can match patterns for websites or consecutive dots.

Comment: @AkSh, you mean, I should split the sentence by using space as a delimiter and test each of the elements?

Comment: yes, something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 cases:

- Two dots with letters between them.
- Two consecutive dots with letters before them.
- Two consecutive dots with letters after them.

Write all 3 as regex and combine using the `|` OR pattern.

```regex
\.\p{L}+\.|\p{L}\.{2}|\.{2}\p{L}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Andreas! Tested this and it works for my needs. Here's the result: https://regex101.com/r/qMsICt/1